# stop event bubbling of a button within an anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am having a button inside an anchor tag, button click is bubbling to anchor tag and anchor tag navigates to the specified href.
I tried event.stopPropagation() and event.cancelBubble but its not useful.
please suggest me solution..

```
function deleteTask(event, taskId) {

            if (event.stopPropagation) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
            else if(event.cancelBubble){
                event.cancelBubble = false;
            }
            $.jqmConfirmation("Delet Task", "Delete task " + taskId +Delete);

            function Delete(button) {
                if (button == "1") {
                    taskList.deleteTaskUsingId(taskId);
                }
            };
        }
<li>
 <a class="ui-btn text-left ui-corner-all" href="GroupTaskViewEdit.html#?      id={{id}}&type={{type}}"  rel="external">

                      <span class="order-number"><b>{{id}}</b></span>

                      <button class="order-number btn" onclick="deleteTask(event,{{id}});" aria-label="Delete">
                                   <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-     hidden="true"></i>
                      </button>
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score 1):

I found this Answer.and its working fine.
I should use 
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

stopPropagation stops events from bubbling up, in this case you still clicked on the link since it wraps the span so you need to stop the browser from doing its default action.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `return false`. This may even work if you are using `.live` in your jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `return false;` in your link: `<a href="#" onclick="deleteTask(); return false;">Delete</a>`

As alternative, use standard jQuery Mobile Split Buttons: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview/#Splitbuttons

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/m1na322y/